# Best Way to Deal with Likely Scam Email

Tags: email

I just received an email from an unknown email and sent to roughly 10 other people in the same mailing list. In it is nothing but a file title "Open 062.xhtml" and the subject is just "ETTWW SWPXE". I am not opening it on any computer I care about. If I just run a VM to download the file and see what it is will my computer or accounts be at any risk? I'm curious to see whether the file is anything interesting as I've never had an email like this. According to Gmail the file is only 256 bytes.

Comment: " I'm curious to see whether the file is anything interesting as I've never had an email like this." The bad guys who write malicious nasties for your PC count on That! Delete them and move on.

Comment: Or just run it in a virtual machine disconnected from the internet and watch the virtual hard drive get ruined while your own OS is intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> file title "Open 062.xhtml" and the subject is just "ETTWW SWPXE".

With over 99.99% certainty, that is not only spam, but may well lead to other malware like encrypting your files.

The possible risk is very high as Ransomware spreads very readily.

Just delete these immediately and do NOT try to trace them.

Almost all of these are in my spam folder and I delete them from there.